# Why is TestID not being converted to INT?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Dev's and DBA's, I think I figured out a bug in SQL 2008 R2, unless one of you can explain the below. 
Can you please explain why TestID is being converted to NUMERIC instead of INT in this scenario?
Please be advised that this is just a sample to show you the problem I came across while trying something bigger such as an automation script that will convert data imported from Excel or Notepad that will be nvarchar/float to the appropriate data types, int, numeric, datetime, varchar.

```
CREATE TABLE #CorruptData(
TestID VARCHAR(100)
 );

 GO

INSERT INTO #CorruptData
VALUES ('1'),
   ('2');



SELECT 
     CASE
        WHEN TestID LIKE '[1-9]%' AND TestID NOT LIKE '0%' THEN CAST(TestID AS INT) 
        WHEN TestID LIKE '0%'  THEN CAST(TestID AS NUMERIC(12,2))
   END AS TestID


 INTO #FixedData
 FROM #CorruptData


SELECT  *
FROM    #FixedData
```

Comment: It is easier to understand if you change your second THEN statement to CAST(TestID + 10 AS NUMERIC(12,2))

Comment: The problem is that the plan was to use an automation script to change any columns that contain possible INT values to INT and Numeric values to Numeric.... adding the +10 to the TestID won't do the trick if I need a column to actually be Numeric :)

Comment: I am pretty sure it has sth. to do with this: [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) (but I am not sure yet why numeric is not in this list, though IMHO it is pretty similar to decimal and as you see decimal takes higher precedence than int and you select both in the same column, hence both is converted to numeric)....Aw commented maybe a bit too quick, just saw your inserted test values maybe I am not so sure anymore :D

Comment: found a post about this, [TSQL seems to always analyze all branches even if they're not hit](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/mssqlserver/sql-server-case-when-data-type-problems/) so Data Type Precedence should also be relevant in this case.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks DrCopyPaste, I'll try to see if I can find some other way to cast them. If not then I'll have to give up on automation and just do it the old fashioned way, column by column :)

Comment: Why do you want to convert _corrupt_ values at all? You should treat corrupt data as strings and let user, who is reviewing and altering it decide what it is. Just leave it as `VARCHAR`. Or put into 2 different columns.

Comment: I have a feeling that your question is a part of wider problem, ypur trying to solve. If you share your wider problem, we'll be able to understand your situation and provide much better reasoned answer.

Comment: @Stoleg - it's part of my job, that's what I do, fix corrupt data and assign the appropriate data types to data imported from Excel/CSV/XML/.txt etc..  :-)

Comment: Then you definitely need to explain the whole process you do, so we can help with the process. SQL server does not assign data types to individual rows or cells in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1 and 2 got converted to decimal due to the way a CASE statement returns the type:

> **CASE**
>
> Result Types Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types
>   in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For
>   more information, see Data Type Precedence.

Read the full documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx

If you really want to see INT, then just cast whatever is returned from the CASE statement to INT:

```
CAST(CASE
    WHEN TestID LIKE '[1-9]%' AND TestID NOT LIKE '0%' THEN CAST(TestID AS INT) 
    WHEN TestID LIKE '0%'  THEN CAST(TestID AS NUMERIC(12,2))
END AS INT) AS TestID
```

Comment: Very nice explanation Louie, but unfortunately I need columns that should be NUMERIC to stay NUMERIC and not get casted to INT ! Your explanation will cast them to INT also which shouldn't be the case. Thanks though

Comment: This is not what you asked for, I suggest that you ask a different question so you can get better answers that actually match your acceptance criteria. ^_^

Comment: You cannot have same column in two or more data types. You need to select only one. As you need to keep `Numeric` values, your column should be `NUMERIC[]`. However for display purposes you can convert interger numbers to `VARCHAR()` dropping decimal part.

Comment: @Stoleg - It still won't work, if I have 10 columns in a table and each of them are different, I need them to be converted to the appropriate data types, this will be data imported from Excel and Notepad(.txt) files.

Comment: Appropiate data type - is one, that allows to keep _all_ values from the column. You need to choose a data type for each column, so all data satifies data type definition. If you have a column with integer and numbers with decimal part, you should choose a datatype, that supports decimal part. You will not loose anything in the data, if you store integers as `NUMERIC`.

Comment: @Stoleg - Storing integers as Numeric will be a problem as the data goes for analysis, this should remain INT, perhaps I will be able to figure out another way to do the conversion but I just can't seem to find a logical way, seems like an automation is just out of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Ususaly when you are dealing with incorrent or corrupt data, you should make as less assumptions about it as possible ansd let user, who is reviewing and altering such data, decide what it is.

Also as @Louie Bao said, you cannot have same column in two or more data types. You need to select only one. As you need to keep Numeric values, your column should be NUMERIC[].

So your options are:

- Leave it as VARCHAR
- Put data into 2 different columns `INT` and `Numeric[]`
- Have a singe `NUMERIC` column, but for display purposes convert numbers without decimal part to VARCHAR() looking as integers.

Comment: The old fashioned way was to do CAST(TestID AS INT), CAST(TestDate AS DATETIME), and so on, also with NULLIF() and REPLACE() if necessary, however I am now trying to automate this by creating a stored procedure that will take the Acc Number column that uniquely identifies each row, the main table containing the corrupt data and the new table containing the clean data as input parameters to the stored procedure, is there really no way to automate this so that it will accept the CASE statement for which data type I want it to convert it to depending on the data inside each column?