# SQL values rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I have a column Quantity in table which type is decimal(16,6)

I would like to make a SELECT query from that table that would

- display quantity as integer if it hasn't decimal places like 1 5 1000
- would display quantity with 2 decimal places in other cases like 1.25  5.25  1000.25

I tried:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (Quantity-CAST(Quantity AS int )=0) THEN CAST(Quantity AS int)
ELSE CAST(Quantity AS decimal(16,2)) END
FROM Table
```

but it returns values like 1.00

Is it possible at all? I wonder now if I was actually trying to put two data types into single column? It worked somehow but maybe not as I wished.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server if that matters

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25569569/2186023

Comment: You can do it, but you would have to cast to `VARCHAR` (or nvarchar) and manually format the numbers to your needs, all branches of a case must return the same type (even the branches that won't get hit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing numbers with their external represention. The number 1.23 can be displayed as 1.23 or 1.230 or 1.2300000. The number is always the same here, but the **string** you show is different.

So what you need to do is create a string of the desired format from your number. The function to do this is FORMAT(number, digits).

```
select 
  case
    when quantity = round(quantity,0,1) then format(quantity,'0')
    else format(quantity,'0.00')
  end
from mytable;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdc85/1.

Darn it, you are right FORMAT doesn't exist in SQL Server 2005, so you need a trick. Cast to int or currency depending of whether you want two or zero digits, then cast to varchar in any case, so both expressions result in the same data type.

```
select 
  case
    when quantity = round(quantity,0,1) then convert(varchar, cast(quantity as int), 1)
    else convert(varchar, cast(quantity as money), 1)
  end
from mytable;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdc85/4.

Comment: You may be right but my SQL Server 2005 doesn't support functions like FORMAT. I suppose it must be some recent thing.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought of MySQL somehow. The syntax is a little different for SQL Server. I've edited my answer.

Comment: And even more different for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Yes, this is what I am saying. I cast to varchar to have both results have the same data type.

Comment: sry I deleted my comment while you were responding to it. (was just stating that you cannot have two different datatypes in one case then I saw that you actually were doin a convert to varchar in both cases so i deleted my comment ;))

Answer (score 0):

Check below examples

```
declare @val as decimal(16,6)

set @val = 10.23

select convert(float,ROUND(@val,2))
--OUTPUT: 10.23

set @val = 10

select convert(float,ROUND(@val,2))
--OUTPUT: 10

set @val = 10.12345

select convert(float,ROUND(@val,2))
--OUTPUT: 10.12
```

The issue here is that if there is a value like `10.10000` it will be displayed as `10.1`

Another thing you could do which would be the recommendation is that you let it be as is from SQL and format it in your View as needed.